# UITableViewCell with custom image drawn in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have my own custom UITableViewCell and I want to draw an image for it right in a cell class. I'm using this code:

```
- (UIImage *)drawImageWithIdentifier:(NSString *)currencyIdentifier inView:(UIImageView *)imageView {

NSLog(@"width: %f, height: %f", imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);

ColorTable *colorTable = [[ColorTable alloc] init];

CGFloat contentInset = imageView.frame.size.height/4;

UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.imageView.bounds];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [colorTable colorWithID:currencyIdentifier];

UIImage *currencyImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dollar_icon.png"];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(backgroundView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:backgroundView.bounds cornerRadius:backgroundView.frame.size.height/2] addClip];

[backgroundView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

CGFloat aspectRatio = currencyImage.size.width/currencyImage.size.height;

if (aspectRatio < 1) {
    //vertical image
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, (backgroundView.frame.size.height - 2*contentInset) *aspectRatio , backgroundView.frame.size.height - 2*contentInset);
    CGFloat pointX = (backgroundView.frame.size.width / 2) - (imageRect.size.width / 2);
    CGFloat pointY = (backgroundView.frame.size.height / 2) - (imageRect.size.height / 2);

    [currencyImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(pointX, pointY, imageRect.size.width, imageRect.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.1];
}
else if (aspectRatio > 1) {
    //horizontal image
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, (backgroundView.frame.size.height - 2*contentInset) *aspectRatio, backgroundView.frame.size.height - 2*contentInset);
    CGFloat pointX = (backgroundView.frame.size.width / 2) - (imageRect.size.width / 2);
    CGFloat pointY = (backgroundView.frame.size.height / 2) - (imageRect.size.height / 2);

    [currencyImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(pointX, pointY, imageRect.size.width, imageRect.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.1];
}
else if (aspectRatio == 1) {
    //square image
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundView.frame.size.height - 2*contentInset, backgroundView.frame.size.height - 2*contentInset);
    CGFloat pointX = (backgroundView.frame.size.width / 2) - (imageRect.size.width / 2);
    CGFloat pointY = (backgroundView.frame.size.height / 2) - (imageRect.size.height / 2);

    [currencyImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(pointX, pointY, imageRect.size.width, imageRect.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.1];
}

UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return finalImage;
}
```

In a regular view controller it draws an image without any kind of problems, but when I put this code in cell class I receive an error like this `<Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.`

What should I do to successfully draw an image for UITableViewCell programmatically?

**UPDATE:**

I found out that it was my mistake because I used `self.imageView.bounds` as size parameter for `backgroundView`. I've designed my cell in IB and my cell class uses `self.currencyImage` as `UIImageView`. Error no longer appears, but my `self.currencyImage` is still empty.

**UPDATE 2:**

I finally found the mistake I made: 
In `.h` file of my UITableViewCell I have a string Property which should be passed to `- (UIImage *)drawImageWithIdentifier:(NSString *)currencyIdentifier inView:(UIImageView *)imageView` as `currencyIdentifier`. But it appears that `currencyIdentifier` is NULL despite the fact that I'm doing `cell.currencyIdentifier = @"USD";` in TableViewController.

Comment: Refrain from doing any heavy processing where tableviewcell is created ....Rather than get your images in a array and then pass them into tableviewcell.

Comment: @PulkitKumarSingh please check my update

Comment: ok....drawImageWithIdentifier... when are you calling this function ?

Comment: @PulkitKumarSingh I'm calling this function in [awakeFromNib] method. The problem is that I pass `currencyIdentifier` to cell's class, but when I call `currencyIdentifier` it appears to be `NULL`. The method itself works well, but it can't get color and image for drawing without `currencyIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with this code

```
 [currencyImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(pointX, pointY, imageRect.size.width, imageRect.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.1];
```

Dont use draw rect inside the UITableViewCell

Create your image and then add as a subview to cell

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.addsubview = yourImage 


    return cell
    }

    Hope this helps.

    Try it out and let me know your result
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't cal DrawRect in loop. its costly method.

create images in a separate loop add them in array and use it.

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

[cell addSubView:[self drawImageWithIdentifier:@"Identifier" inView:cell.contentView]];

 return cell
```